# On what site are questions about digital cameras allowed?

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog

I'm unsure if "allowed" is the most appropriate word, but I recently had a issue with my digital camera and placed the question on Super User. I got an answer but a day or so later, it got downvoted and closed. Is there another more approprite StackExchange site for this kind of inquiry?

Comment: Question has been migrated http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/33936/turned-off-digital-camera-with-the-lens-open-now-theres-a-lens-error don't forget to register with the same details you did on SU

Comment: I wonder, should this meta question be migrated to meta.SE?

Comment: Also, someone please remove the [superuser-blog] tag from this question and the [questions] tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions dealing with the camera alone may be better fit on [Photos Stack Exchange](https://photo.stackexchange.com/about).

If your issue involves docking or connecting with the computer then it should be okay here on Super User as well.

Comment: Thank you! How would I migrate my question: http://superuser.com/questions/540898/i-turned-off-my-digital-camera-with-the-lens-open-now-theres-a-lens-error ?